# How can an error message be set for the Spinner in Android?

Tags: android, android-widget, spinner

I'd like to be able to call code like this, similar to how `setError` is set on a TextView:

```
spinner.setError("Error message");
```

However, `setError` only works for an EditText, not for a Spinner.

I want to notify the user if the spinner field is not selected. How can I perform such a notification **without using a Toast**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a setError() for the Spinner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749971/creating-a-seterror-for-the-spinner)

Comment: Seterror method is not available for spinner..u have to create other function or toast message to show it.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

There are a few solutions in this thread [Creating a setError() for the Spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749971/creating-a-seterror-for-the-spinner):

The *EdmundYeung99*'s one works for me, either you are using your own adapter or not.
Just put the following code in your validate function:

```
TextView errorText = (TextView)mySpinner.getSelectedView();
errorText.setError("");
errorText.setTextColor(Color.RED);//just to highlight that this is an error
errorText.setText("my actual error text");//changes the selected item text to this
```

But, make sure you have at least one value in the Spinner adapter when you are doing your verification. If not, like an empty adapter waiting to be populate, make your adapter get an empty String:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[]{""});
mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Spent hours looking for a way to do this, this is the best solution.

Comment: Works like charm, Thanks

Comment: Works as long as getSelectedView() doesn't return null.

Comment: That's why i added: 
"But, make sure you have at least one value in the Spinner adapter when you are doing your verification. If not, like an empty adapter waiting to be populate, make your adapter get an empty String"

Comment: it work only for first action, but if i validate again when the spinner or textview still show error msg it doesn't work! @LionelT.

Answer (score 42):

Spinner class will return a textview when you use `getSelectedView()`. So you can use `setError()` indirectly.

```
((TextView)spinner.getSelectedView()).setError("Error message");
```

Results should be like ...

[image: setError in spinner]

Hope It will be helpful!

Comment: Very good idea but it breaks if no item is selected, in that case it returns null.

Comment: Solution is not about to satisfy all the cases. There may be several other conditions and use cases. It's depend on you how you're making use of this snippet. :)

Comment: This only shows that there is an error on the spinner. It doesn't allude to what the error is...

Comment: I've just point out how setError() can be used with spinner. Even you also know set error is not a good approach to show error of spinner. I've just answered the question. If you really want to show message immediately then why are you not requesting focus on it!

Answer (score 3):

[Here is a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29956372/3063884) that uses a hidden TextView to get a pop-up message to appear, in addition to the error icon in the spinner. When in an error state, the Spinner looks like this:

[image: Spinner in invalid state]

When not in an error state, it looks like this.

[image: Spinner in valid state]

The complete solution is documented here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29956372/3063884

Answer (score 3):

for people who are looking for a Kotlin answer

```
val errorText = spinnerclient.selectedView as TextView
                errorText.error = "client required"
                errorText.requestFocus()
                return@setOnClickListener
```

The focus was returned but the text wasn't displayed. I will update once its displayed