# Android: for loop through EditText, CheckBoxed and Spinners to setErrors

Tags: android, for-loop, textview, android-spinner

This piece of code gets resources from a list and set errors for each field on a registration form, one of them is a spinner, so when the error is on the spinner, it fails due to the fact that the spinner is not a subclass of TextView. How can I get this code deal with the spinner in an elegant way?

```
// set errors
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> error : errors.entrySet()) {
            int id = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier("edit_" + error.getKey(), "id", getActivity().getPackageName());
            //TODO this codes doen't manage spinner errors! (checkboxes and editext are both TextView)
            TextView edit = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(id);
            if (!error.getValue().isEmpty()) {
                edit.setError(error.getValue().get(0));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the current view is an instance of a textview. If it is, then go ahead and cast it to a TextView, and perform whatever operations you were performing over it. Else, handle checkboxes/spinner/whatever in any way you'd like.

```
 for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> error : errors.entrySet()) {
        int id = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier("edit_" + error.getKey(), "id", getActivity().getPackageName());

        View edit = getActivity().findViewById(id);
        if (!error.getValue().isEmpty() && edit instanceof TextView) {
             TextView editTextView = (TextView)edit;
             editTextView.setError(error.getValue().get(0));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Urban, this seems that will jump the spinner fields, isn't it? I actually would like to display errors on the spinners as well as on the editText views using the same compact code.

Comment: Yes, this will skip the spinners. You'll have to do a bit more work to have a `setError` method for your spinner. Follow this link to see how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749971/creating-a-seterror-for-the-spinner
Once that is implemented, you may have to add another if condition for your spinner.

Comment: Ok and this code (as it is) gives a warning while trying to cast a variable to itself. It also give an error on setError method because it doesn't convert "edit" variable of type View into "edit" variable of type "TextView".

Comment: What's the error? I'm able to cast a View to a TextView without any problems. You can safely ignore the warnings here, however, if you'd like to fix those warnings, you can just create another variable, cast the View to a TextView, and then assign this to the new variable.

Comment: that's what I did because if I leave like that it gave me an error on setErrors and a warning in the casting line.

Comment: ok, so are there still errors? Or the error was fixed by assigning it to a new variable?

Comment: the error has been fixed by assigning it to a new variable.

Comment: Cool, I'll make the change in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I solved it, many thanks to [Urban](https://stackoverflow.com/users/595947/urban)

```
 // set errors
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> error : errors.entrySet()) {
            int id = getActivity().getResources().getIdentifier("edit_" + error.getKey(), "id", getActivity().getPackageName());
            View edit = getActivity().findViewById(id);

            if (!error.getValue().isEmpty() && edit instanceof TextView) {
                TextView mTextView;
                mTextView = (TextView)edit;
                mTextView.setError(error.getValue().get(0));
            } else if (!error.getValue().isEmpty() && edit instanceof Spinner){
                Spinner mSpinner;
                mSpinner = (Spinner)edit;
                ((TextView)mSpinner.getChildAt(0)).setError(error.getValue().get(0));
            }
        }
```