# How to make Spinner error like edit text in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner

I have a spinner in which I have list of country, what I want if user does not select country name from list I want to show error in spinner like edit text.How to perform this ?

**code for spinner :**

```
    /*Country Spinner*/
    m_countrySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.country_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CCountryStorage> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.country_spinner, CCountryListStorage.item);
    m_countrySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    m_countrySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            CCountryStorage operatorName = CCountryListStorage.item[position];
            m_selectedCountryCode = operatorName.code;
            Log.e(TAG, "Operator code:-" + m_selectedCountryCode);
            mSpinnerItem = m_countrySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
            if (position > 0) {
                checkForEmptyField();
            } else {

                m_RegisterButton.setEnabled(false);
                m_RegisterButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(192, 192, 192));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: what is the error

Comment: did you solve your problem or not ?

Answer (score 1):

`Spinner` class will return a `textview` when you use `getSelectedView()`. So you can use `setError()` indirectly.

```
 ((TextView)spinner.getSelectedView()).setError("Your Error msg Here");
```

**For Better Understanding :**

> #### getSelectedView()
>
> **View** :    The view corresponding to the currently selected item, or null if nothing is selected.
>
> and it will return the `TextView`. so we can set error as i mention
> above.

For more detail visit the documentation : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions hers [Creating a setError() for the Spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3749971/creating-a-seterror-for-the-spinner).
Just put the following code in your validate function:

```
TextView errorText = (TextView)mySpinner.getSelectedView();
errorText.setError("");
errorText.setTextColor(Color.RED);//just to highlight that this is an error
errorText.setText("my actual error text");//changes the selected item text to this
```

But, make sure you have at least one value in the Spinner adapter when you are doing your verification. If not, like an empty adapter waiting to be populate, make your adapter get an empty String:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, new String[]{""});
mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Cheers!